# xperf - CPU cycle consumed by Process for given pair of ETW events

Tags: xperf

Scenario:
1.       Started Xperf.

2. App is started. There are ETW events (E1, E2) in App.
3. While running App, ETW(E1,E2) events are raised, the (T1,T2) are timestamps corresponding to (E1, E2) events.
4. Stop Xperf. ETL file is generated.
5. The (T1,T2) timestamps are obtained from ETL file.

Query:
How to get the CPU cycle consumed by App between timestamps (T1,T2) using xperf?

Comment: is the question answered or do you need more details?

Answer (score 0):

Open the ETL in [WPA.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448170.aspx), drag and drop the [CPU Usage (Sampling) and Generic Events to the analysis pane](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448179.aspx).

Select the time between Event 1 and 2 and click "Zoom". Now go to the CPU Sampling graph and filter the graph to only include your application. Now you see the number of Counts and the % of the CPU usage of your app during the duration between the 2 events.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to get CPU cycle consumed by App between timestamps (T1,T2) via Command-Line?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn926926(v=vs.85).aspx. But it looks like this don't include a filtering for a process.